# How can one USB port report 2 different BUS IDs?

Tags: usb, lsusb

I'm following [this guide on passing through an entire USB controller](https://lime-technology.com/forums/topic/35112-guide-passthrough-entire-pci-usb-controller/) to a VM.

At one point he says to plug in a flash drive to every USB port on the computer to see which ports correspond to which bus.

Weird thing is that I plugged 2 different devices into the same port, and lsusb always reported BUS 3 for one device, and BUS 4 for the other.

Why is that?

Comment: could be one device is USB2 the other is USB3, which will "route" to a different controller or port or whatever

Comment: That's what I'm suspecting now as well. Darn

Comment: BTW, `lsusb -t` really helps to debug which port belongs to which root, including the distinction between USB2 and USB3.

Answer (score 2):

After a bit more testing, I found that any USB 3 device plugged into a USB 3 slot was mapped to BUS 4. Any USB 2 device plugged into any USB 3 slot was mapped to BUS 3.

However any USB 3 device plugged into a USB 2 slot was mapped to BUS 3.

Seems that the LCD determines the BUS.